# ViewPager ListViews seem to update each other's adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment, android-arrayadapter

New android dev here. Been battling with the same problem now for a bit and it's time to ask for help. I have an app that extends the FragmentPagerAdapter in a FragmentActivity (utilizing the android.support.app.v4 library), and the first 2 pages contain list Fragments (not ListFragments, mind you, regular Fragments that I am putting ListViews on). Basically, my app sends over some data from a service to a custom ArrayAdapter. The trick is, the ListViews on the first and second pages are based on the same data; ultimately, there's going to be some different rendering and biz logic applied to each, but for now I was just trying to get both lists to appear. For the purposes of this test, each list should start out with the same data, and each item in the list has a button; clicking the button should make that row disappear from the list in the current fragment, but not from the list in the other. Here's my code:

```
public class CustomBillAdapterTest extends ArrayAdapter<MasterBill> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<MasterBill> billRows;
int resourceID;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public FragmentActivity fragment;

public ImageLoader imageLoader;
AppService as;

public CustomBillAdapterTest(FragmentActivity fragment, int resourceID, ArrayList<MasterBill> billRows) {
    super(fragment, resourceID, billRows);
    this.context = fragment;
    this.billRows = billRows;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.resourceID = resourceID;

    try {       
        as = (AppService) fragment.getApplicationContext();         
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(fragment.getApplication());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getCount() {
    return billRows.size();
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MasterBill master = getItem(position);

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.fragment.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(resourceID, null);
    }

    TextView itemText = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    TextView price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.price);
    ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);
    Button button = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    itemText.setText(master.item_text);
    price.setText(master.price);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(master.icon, itemIcon);

    Log.d("position", Integer.toString(position));

    button.setTag(position);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(fragment, "test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            billRows.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }); 
    return vi;
}
```

And then here's the code from the Fragment, back in the main activity class:

```
public static class MyBillFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView list;
    private static CustomBillAdapterTest adapter;

    public MyBillFragment newInstance() {
        MyBillFragment myBill = new MyBillFragment();
        return myBill;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }       

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybill_frag, container, false);

    }   

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        list = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomBillAdapterTest(this.getActivity(), R.layout.mybill_frag_listitem, myBill);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Then there's another duplicate class, just like that one, except different name and it passes a different (but initially duplicate) ArrayList to the adapter.

Here's the problem: when I fire it up, both pages of lists appears properly, but when I click on the button for a list item in one page, an item disappears from the list in the other page. And not the same item--always the last one from the other page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're doing:

```
ArrayList<MasterBill> listOne = someFunctionThatReturnsAList();

ArrayList<MasterBill> listTwo = listOne;
```

If this is what you're doing, then you are creating two variables that point to the same list, which would create the problem you are facing.

The right way would be to use the copy constructor:

```
ArrayList<MasterBill> listTwo = new ArrayList<MasterBill>(listOne);
```

Comment: You're right! Clearly need to brush up on my Java. I was setting those two objects by calling the same method ( a = x.y(); b = x.y(); ). I guess Java considers that as a reference to the same object?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I guess in your case `y()` is returning an instance of the same ArrayList. e.g. if `y()` is a getter for an ArrayList held by `x`, it would always return a reference to the same object.